# Working UPDATE query in SQL Server is not "an updateable query" in Access

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2013

I have a query that I typed in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio:

```
UPDATE RidesTbl 
SET fname = (SELECT fname FROM Users 
             WHERE username='Dani'), 
    lname = (SELECT lname FROM Users 
             WHERE username='Dani') 
WHER Eusername = 'Dani'
```

The query is working as expected and everything is good on server management, but when I try to run the same query in MS Access 2013 I get the following message:

> Operation must use and updateable query

I have read that it causes because "read only" situation, but I don't have problems to insert or delete any data from 'RidesTbl' table, so probably it's not the case here.

Any help would be appreciated to help me solve that problem.

Comment: My guess is that the linked table in Access is read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server uses Transact-SQL (T-SQL) and Access uses Access SQL. They are two quite different dialects of SQL.

A "direct translation" of your T-SQL query into Access SQL would be

```sql
UPDATE RidesTbl 
SET fname = DLookup("fname","Users","username='Dani'"), 
    lname = DLookup("lname","Users","username='Dani'") 
WHERE Eusername = 'Dani'
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
UPDATE RidesTbl 
  SET (fname, lname) VALUES (
  (SELECT fname FROM Users WHERE username='Dani'), 
  (SELECT lname FROM Users WHERE username='Dani')) 
  WHERE Eusername = 'Dani';
```

Be careful at your "WHERE"!

Comment: Can you add bit of explanation of how this would fix the problem the OP has encountered?